# Get values after submit in jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, submit

I have a form with just one field "search" and a submit button. My jQuery code looks like this:

```
$( "form.qsearch" ).submit(function() {
 alert(inputsearchfield);
})
```

All I am trying to do is simply alert out the value in the search box. I have searched and search online and can't find anything for this simple code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hwn1p2L9/)

```
<form id="sForm">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('#sForm').on('submit',function(){
        alert( $('#search').val() );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this on form submit:

```
alert($('#search').val());
```

where 'search' is id of the search input field.

Hope this might help!!

Answer (score 1):

Assign your input with id="searched" // Any id you want..

then simply call

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    alert( $('#searched').val() );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. You may get the value of the input filed like this:

```
var inputField = $('input[name]').val()
and just alert this.

alert(inputField);
```

Here you go.

Answer (score 0):

the submit event handler has to be assigned for form, not for the field inside

```
$( "form" ).submit(function(e) {
    alert($('#search').val());
})
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/pajs7xk8/1/)

Comment: This simply returns the word "search" i need to return the value in the search box.  Thank you.

Comment: @user982853, Just place the value of searchbox inside alert. http://jsfiddle.net/vm8joatL/